# How to dynamically load angular modules after production

Tags: angular, deployment, build, angular-cli

I have an application which is already in production and I want to make it as flexible when I add new features. Features is nothing but additional modules.

In Angular we have to explicitly specify all the dependent sub modules and components in main app module before we build the angular application for production output , it means I couldn't deploy any additional modules as new features after the production.

For example

```
Main Module- Host application which will load the sub modules using routes
NewPageModule1 - SubModule
NewPageModule1 - SubModule
```

Is it possible to have app module dynamically load sub module and render it without recompiling the entire app?

I have already read about [SystemJsNgModuleLoader](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.8/modules/%40angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.ts#L41-L84) , but I am not sure is this one is a good approach to follow.

I need some thoughts or suggestions what all the possible ways to bring this kind of flexibility for the application.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might be interested in the new Angular Elements feature with Angular 6.

https://angular.io/guide/elements

> Angular elements are Angular components packaged as custom elements, a web standard for defining new HTML elements in a framework-agnostic way.

Answer (score -2):

Angular provides a mechanism which is called lazy loading. 
Basically the idea is, that you split your application in several (feature) modules and only if the client really needs or rather requests this part of the application, the specific modules is lazy loaded. 
The big advantage is that you can significantly decrease the initial bundle size and therefor also loading time.

This is a example snippet how you implement lazy loading:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: 'app/customers/customers.module#CustomersModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: 'app/orders/orders.module#OrdersModule'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

see also the official docs: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules
and a medium tutorial: https://medium.com/angularmedellin/lazy-loading-angular-modules-58fc844b5c7d

I also recommend you the webpack-bundle-analyzer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer
to be able to analyze you build output.

Comment: My Question is different , my current application is loading child modules using angular lazy loading feature but I have to specify this child module in app module. I want to avoid that dependency , instead I have to dynamically load the modules

Comment: sorry, I missunderstood your question. 
Therefore I recommend you these slides: https://speakerdeck.com/manfredsteyer/architectures-for-angular-packages-monorepos-microservices
Manfred als mentions the opportunities of Angular Elements.

Comment: this package/project might also be interesting for you: https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus

(as I understood the purpose of this package, you can optimize your angular elements, so that you are not forced to load all the lets call it angular overhead (angular core, ...) again and again )